# I am implementing linked lists in C, and my addhead function is not working correctly. What's wrong?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am starting to learn C, and trying to implement linked lists. For some reason, my code is not running correcting. My `addtail` and `printlist` functions work fine, but my `addhead` does not.

I cannot figure out what is wrong. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    typedef struct temp_node{
        int data;
        struct temp_node * next;
    } node;

    void addtail(node * head, int taildata){
        node * tail = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tail->data = taildata;
        tail->next = NULL;

        node * current = head;

        while(current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
        }

        current->next = tail;
    }

    void addhead(node ** head, int headdata){
        node * newhead = malloc(sizeof(node));
        newhead->data = headdata;
        newhead->next = *head;
        *head = newhead;
    }

    void printlist(node * head){
        node * current = head;

        while(current != NULL){
            printf("%d\n", current->data);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    node * head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->data = 0;
    head->next = NULL;

    addtail(head, 1);
    addtail(head, 2);
    addhead(head, 5);

    printlist(head);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it (on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) I get the following output:

```
6299760
1
2
```

Why is this not changing the head of the list correctly?

Comment: You have functions defined within another function (`main`). This is not valid C.

Comment: `addhead(head, 5);` --> `addhead(&head, 5);` Also You need `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Are you ignoring type errors from your compiler?

Comment: @alpha did you define functions in main ? Or copy mistake while writing on SO ?

Comment: Those answer the question.

Comment: I now have another one: Why in `addtail` I passed the list normally and it worked fine, whereas with `addhead` I have to pass it by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I now have another one: Why in addtail I passed the list normally and it worked fine, whereas with addhead I have to pass it by reference?

Both of the ways work fine. Either you pass pointer to node like this:

```
addhead(node * head, int headdata)
```

and call it like this:
 `addhead(head,5)`

Or  pass a pointer to pointer to a node (2D pointer) :

```
 addhead(node ** head, int headdata)
```

and call it by passing a reference of pointer to head (i.e. a 2D pointer) this way:

```
addhead(&head,5)
```

I hope it helps!